# Sorting and searching operation is not performing in my code

Tags: angular

Here we have one user class and address class. user and address has one to one relationship. I have implemented code for sorting and searching, it is not working out.

I have used same code for another component which is list of users, for users component it is working fine but it is not working for address. please help me out. I dont know why it is not working. I think this has one to one relation, so maybe we can't get or give some proper things why it is not working for this particular component.

address.component.html:

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="table_header">
    <h1 class="heading">Address Details</h1>
    <div class="search-container">
   
      <input matInput placeholder="search" autocomplete="off" (keyup)="filterData($event)">

  </div>
  </div>
  
<div class="table_container">
  <table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource" >


    <ng-container matColumnDef="doorNumber">
      <th  style="font-size:16px;" mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Door Number </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.addressID.doorNumber}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="streetName">
      <th  style="font-size:16px;" mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Street Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.addressID.streetName}} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="areaName">
      <th style="font-size:16px;" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Area Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.addressID.areaName }} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="districtName">
      <th  style="font-size:16px;" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DistrictName </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.addressID.districtName}} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="pinCode">
      <th style="font-size:16px;" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Pincode </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.addressID.pinCode}} </td>
    </ng-container>

   

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="paginator">
<mat-paginator #paginator [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my address.component.ts:

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-address',
      templateUrl: './address.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./address.component.css']
    })
    export class AddressComponent implements OnInit {
    
 displayedColumns = ['doorNumber', 'streetName', 'areaName', 'districtName', 'pinCode'];
      dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<any>;
    
      @ViewChild('paginator') paginator!: MatPaginator;
      @ViewChild(MatSort) matSort!: MatSort;
    
      constructor(private addressService: AlldetailsService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.addressService.getAllDetails().subscribe((response) => {
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response);
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          this.dataSource.sort = this.matSort;
          console.log('response is', response);
        })
    
      }
    
      filterData($event: any) {
        this.dataSource.filter = $event.target.value;
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: Does the address service's object match the names of your displayed columns?

Comment: I am getting the all details from the one end point. This end point consist of all details. So we can delete it, and those are matching.@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AlldetailsService {
  baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:8080/user/users';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getAllDetails(): Observable<AllDetails[]> {
    return this.http.get<AllDetails[]>(this.baseUrl);
  }

  deleteAlldetails(userId: any)  {
    return this.http.delete('http://localhost:8080/user/users/' + userId);
  }


}